# Iteratively collect "solve" elements in a for loop in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I am trying to collect the x y values from a `solve` command that is within a `for loop`.  I am trying to put the x y values into an array for each run of the "r" value.

Here is my code:

```
syms x y;

r = 1:10;

for k = 1:10

[solx, soly] = solve(x^2*r(k) + y == 0, 2*x + 3*y*r(k) == 50)

xx(k) = solx(1);
yy(k) = soly(1);

end
```

I get large values like `(149^(1/2)*1i)/3 + 1/3
 1/3 - (149^(1/2)*1i)/3`.  Can you tell me how I can put those values in a 'normal number' form to be saved into the array...like `0.3333 - 4.0689i`?Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to cast the result of `solve` to format `double` in the loop:

```
clc
clear

syms x y;

r = 1:10;

for k = 1:10

[solx, soly] = solve(x^2*r(k) + y == 0, 2*x + 3*y*r(k) == 50);

%// HERE. Use double()
xx(k) = double(solx(1));
yy(k) = double(soly(1));

end
```

Now `xx`, for example, looks like this:

```
xx =

  Columns 1 through 2

   0.3333 + 4.0689i   0.0833 + 2.0395i

  Columns 3 through 4

   0.0370 + 1.3603i   0.0208 + 1.0204i

  Columns 5 through 6

   0.0133 + 0.8164i   0.0093 + 0.6804i

  Columns 7 through 8

   0.0068 + 0.5832i   0.0052 + 0.5103i

  Columns 9 through 10

   0.0041 + 0.4536i   0.0033 + 0.4082i
```

yay!